# Convert from int and num to factor

Tags: r

From this dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4),
                 scores = c(-1.1,0.2,1.3,-0.4),
                 col2 = c(1,0,1,0),
                 col2 = c(1,1,1,1), col3 = c(-0.3,-0.2,3.3,-2.4))
```

if we use str(df) we can see that columns are int or num.

How is it possible to convert to factor.

Example like the str(df) of this dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c('1','2','3','4'),
                    scores = c('-1.1','0.2','1.3','-0.4'),
                    col2 = c('1','0','1','0'),
col2 = c('1','1','1','1'), col3 = c('-0.3','-0.2','3.3','-2.4'))
```

Comment: `df[] <- lapply(df, as.factor)`

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyverse`, we can use `mutate_all`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate_all(factor)
```